# Any Suggestion for Optimization of Query with EO model?

Tags: java, jdbc, webobjects

I am trying to fetch data from a table which have very huge data some.
i am using Java Webobject and EOmodel.
While i am trying to fetch with a indexed column i am able to get the result in less than 2 sec. But when i am trying to search with any other column its almost taking 30+ sec.
the query which is hitting through the EOmodel , am hitting directly with a JDBC standalone it fetches the result in 1.5sec.

Any suggestion for setting any flag in fetch specification or so to fetch the result fast.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the difference in the SQL generated by EOF fetch compared to your JDBC fetch?

How many items in the result? (if there are 10,'s of thousands, then the time may be converting from raw SQL result to EOEnterpriseObjects).

Try setFetchesRawRows(true) on your EOFetchSpecification and that will probably give you a comparable result to the JDBC fetch if your result set is large.

Finally, if you have caching enabled on your database, and you ran the JDBC fetch right after the EOF fetch for comparison purposes, the JDBC fetch might be just getting cached results from the SQL cache.

Bottom line, you are not providing enough information here for anyone to be able to offer really targeted advice.

Comment: Only difference i am making in the SQL fetch and the JDBC fetch is the Date format . in SQL fetch i am giving the

Comment: Thanks for your help :) Only difference i am making in the SQL fetch and the JDBC fetch is the Date format . in SQL fetch i am giving the date in 'dd-MMM-yyyy' and in EO generated query i am passing date object it is converting the into date format with 'Fri May 27 00:00:00 PDT 2011 ' . to confirm the time is taken only for setting entity i removed all the columns other than two from class properties of plist and from entity class also . still it is taking the same 30-40sec . is there any way to get the entity object from rawrows . i tried hitting rawrows. its fast nearly 2 sec.

Comment: i will try out different fetches with JDBC for confirmation is that really cache.

Comment: So if raw rows is fast, then the time is being used in conversion of raw SQL results to EOEnterpriseObjects.

Comment: So if raw rows is fast, then the time is being used in conversion of raw SQL results to EOEnterpriseObjects. In this scenario, we usually do one of two things. (1) Fetch and process results in batches using something like [http://webobjects.mdimension.com/hudson/job/Wonder/javadoc/er/extensions/eof/ERXFetchSpecificationBatchIterator.html] or (2) Fetch raw rows and convert to fully 'hydrated' EOEnterpriseObjects using EOUtilities.html.objectFromRawRow(...). BTW, you can safely pass a large set of raw rows to a background thread (Runnable) and perform processing with or without user status page

Comment: Finally, you should join the community mailing lists and ask questions there to get better and more answers to WebObjects questions. [http://lists.apple.com/mailman/listinfo/webobjects-dev], and if not using Project WOnder, you should be [http://wiki.objectstyle.org/confluence/display/WONDER/Home]

Comment: Thanks a bunch .... :) i will try out the above ideas and keep post the result.... yeah need to join those forums ...

Comment: if the "raw SQL results to EOEnterpriseObjects" conversion is taking time then when i try to do a fetch with 2 columns in plist and corresponding entity object as per assumption it should fetch fast. but when i tried this scenario i got same delay !